# Importing a extended attribute in schema in AD , does it need mAPIID put into LDIF file?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, schema, ldif, mapi

What exactly is mAPIId and should it be put into the ldif file when the schema is imported into a AD forest?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no.  mAPIID is actually mapiID and is messaging related.  Unless your new attribute is mapi-related, you likely don't need it.  Plus, [this MS doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675883(v=vs.85).aspx) lists the required fields for an attribute and mapiID is not listed.